# input type file invisible on page load

Tags: html, input, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, shadowbox

I have this problem Only on IE7 and IE8.

I have a shadowbox that contains an input type file in it.

When this shadowbox is loaded, the input file is invisible... until I mouse hover it.

It's a reall basic form with a really basic input file:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="file" name="img" onChange="$('#button_img').css('display','');" />
  <input type="hidden" name="step_crop" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="" />
</form>
```

I tried to delete everything on the file and only leave the form with one element which is, yeah, the evil input file, but still invisible on page load until I hover it.

Someone would have an idea ?

(Video link for the behavior: http://www.screenr.com/6ICH )

Answer (score 1):

Please try to close your div and input tags properly. does it work?

Hi, I can see input field in both IE7 and IE8. Can you please add your view how it looks like before and after

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post, I misscopied the text from my editor

Comment: I just edited my post and added a video link of the behavior. as you will see, the input is not showed until it is hovered

Comment: Try with lightbox instead

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, but I'm alread using shadowbox everywhere in the website, I can't change it for one page..